# Finding most recent files in a partition on Windows

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, sorting, file-search

I am using Windows 7, and my C partition is almost full. What i want is to find the most recently added files in this partition. How can I do this?

Alternatively, the question can be formulated as: how do I sort by date all the files in a certain partition?

Comment: you can click on the arrow of `Date Modified` in details view of your C

Comment: the details view of C only shows the folders which are direct children of C. What i want is to see every file that is on C (like, for example, files saved on Desktop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to C: and type * in the search bar.

This will display everything there is in a certain partition.

From there Right Click anywhere in the Explorer > Sort By > Date Modified

Comment: I did what you said, however files are grouped by extension first: all folders, all word documents, all dll files, all exe files. Within a group of files with the same extension, files are indeed sorted by date. However, i wanted all files to be grouped by the date modified, no matter their extension

Comment: I am sure there's a filter added for grouping files by extensions. Try removing that filter and you will have all the results grouped only by date.